# Username should be email AWSAmplify Error

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm trying to integrate the Amplify Authentication in my android app, however I'm getting this error instead:

> E/UserContextDataProvider: Exception in creating JSON from context data
> E/AuthQuickStart: Sign up failed
> InvalidParameterException{message=One or more parameters are incorrect., cause=com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.InvalidParameterException: Username should be an email. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: b533589a-f3e9-4f6a-a0f9-9a665369fc19), recoverySuggestion=Enter correct parameters.}
> at com.amplifyframework.auth.cognito.util.CognitoAuthExceptionConverter.lookup(CognitoAuthExceptionConverter.java:79)
> at com.amplifyframework.auth.cognito.AWSCognitoAuthPlugin$2.onError(AWSCognitoAuthPlugin.java:315)

This is my signup function:

```
    val username="Anna "
    val password="PASSword@98"
    val mail="tmock98@gmail.com" 
 binding.loginBtn.setOnClickListener {
        if (viewModel.isValid()) {
            val options = AuthSignUpOptions.builder()
                .userAttribute(AuthUserAttributeKey.email(), mail.trim())
                .build()
            Amplify.Auth.signUp(username.trim(), password.trim(), options,
                { result: AuthSignUpResult ->
                    Log.i(
                        "AuthQuickStart",
                        "Result: $result"
                    )
                    Toast.makeText(context, "all is good", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            ) { error: AuthException? ->
                Log.e(
                    "AuthQuickStart",
                    "Sign up failed",
                    error
                )
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the `error` suggests you need to replace `username` with `email`

```
val username = "tmock98@gmail.com"
```